# Encountered a problem when building my app with Odevio while trying to build ad-hoc

Tags: flutter, mobile

While building my application with [Odevio](https://odevio.com) I got the following error:
Here are my full logs:

I tried to search the internet but nothing seems to help. I would really appreciatesome guidance.

```
Build started at 2023-10-02 22:55:53.933638+00:00
----- Certificate keychain importation -----
1 certificate imported.
1 key imported.
keychain: "/Users/appollo/Library/Keychains/appollo.keychain-db"
version: 512
class: 0x00000010
attributes:
0x00000000 &lt;uint32&gt;=0x00000010
0x00000001 &lt;blob&gt;="Imported Private Key"
0x00000002 &lt;blob&gt;=&lt;NULL&gt;
0x00000003 &lt;uint32&gt;=0x00000001
0x00000004 &lt;uint32&gt;=0x00000000
0x00000005 &lt;uint32&gt;=0x00000000
0x00000006 &lt;blob&gt;=0x22187CE35F2C20150A16558C8EAC63F9A29A07BE ""\030|\343_, \025\012\026U\214\216\254c\371\242\232\007\276"
0x00000007 &lt;blob&gt;=&lt;NULL&gt;
0x00000008 &lt;blob&gt;=0x7B38373139316361322D306663392D313164342D383439612D3030303530326235323132327D00 "{87191ca2-0fc9-11d4-849a-000502b52122}\000"
0x00000009 &lt;uint32&gt;=0x0000002A "\000\000\000*"
0x0000000A &lt;uint32&gt;=0x00000800
0x0000000B &lt;uint32&gt;=0x00000800
0x0000000C &lt;blob&gt;=0x0000000000000000
0x0000000D &lt;blob&gt;=0x0000000000000000
0x0000000E &lt;uint32&gt;=0x00000001
0x0000000F &lt;uint32&gt;=0x00000001
0x00000010 &lt;uint32&gt;=0x00000001
0x00000011 &lt;uint32&gt;=0x00000000
0x00000012 &lt;uint32&gt;=0x00000001
0x00000013 &lt;uint32&gt;=0x00000001
0x00000014 &lt;uint32&gt;=0x00000001
0x00000015 &lt;uint32&gt;=0x00000001
0x00000016 &lt;uint32&gt;=0x00000001
0x00000017 &lt;uint32&gt;=0x00000001
0x00000018 &lt;uint32&gt;=0x00000001
0x00000019 &lt;uint32&gt;=0x00000001
0x0000001A &lt;uint32&gt;=0x00000001
----- Provisioning profile importation -----
----- Unzipping sources -----
----- Git patch initialization -----
DELETED THIS PART TO POST THE QUESTION
----- Flutter preparation -----
----- Creating export.plist file -----
----- Modifying XCode config -----
----- Pod install -----
Analyzing dependencies
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:34:in `force_encoding': can't modify frozen String (FrozenError)
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:34:in `report'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in `report_error'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in `handle_exception'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/bin/pod:55:in `&lt;top (required)&gt;'
from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `&lt;main&gt;'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/nanaimo-0.3.0/lib/nanaimo/reader.rb:284:in `raise_parser_error': [!] Dictionary missing value for key "DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = G22SPKBM49;\n\t\t\t\tENABLE_BITCODE = NO;\r\n\t\t\t\tINFOPLIST_FILE = Runner/Info.plist;\r\n\t\t\t\tINFOPLIST_KEY_CFBundleDisplayName = Voxio;\r\n\t\t\t\tIPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 13.0;\r\n\t\t\t\tLD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = (\r\n\t\t\t\t\t", expected '=' and found "$" (Nanaimo::Reader::ParseError)
# -------------------------------------------
# LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = (
#
948&gt; "$(inherited)",
^
# "@executable_path/Frameworks",
# -------------------------------------------
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/nanaimo-0.3.0/lib/nanaimo/reader.rb:190:in `parse_dictionary'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/nanaimo-0.3.0/lib/nanaimo/reader.rb:132:in `parse_object'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/nanaimo-0.3.0/lib/nanaimo/reader.rb:193:in `parse_dictionary'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/nanaimo-0.3.0/lib/nanaimo/reader.rb:132:in `parse_object'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/nanaimo-0.3.0/lib/nanaimo/reader.rb:193:in `parse_dictionary'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/nanaimo-0.3.0/lib/nanaimo/reader.rb:132:in `parse_object'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/nanaimo-0.3.0/lib/nanaimo/reader.rb:193:in `parse_dictionary'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/nanaimo-0.3.0/lib/nanaimo/reader.rb:132:in `parse_object'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/nanaimo-0.3.0/lib/nanaimo/reader.rb:107:in `parse!'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.22.0/lib/xcodeproj/plist.rb:27:in `read_from_path'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.22.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:211:in `initialize_from_file'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.22.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:113:in `open'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1194:in `block (2 levels) in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1193:in `each'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1193:in `block in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1188:in `inspect_targets_to_integrate'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:107:in `analyze'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:422:in `analyze'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:244:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:243:in `resolve_dependencies'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:162:in `install!'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/bin/pod:55:in `&lt;top (required)&gt;'
from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `&lt;main&gt;'
Error updating sources. Exit code 1
Build stop order received at 2023-10-02 22:58:14.167094+00:00
```

While building my application with [Odevio](https://odevio.com) I got the following error message:
Sources update - Error updating sources - Error code 74
[Odevio](https://odevio.com)

[Odevio](https://odevio.com)

Comment: Hello,

I believe this could help you, it looks like the user had the same issue.

https://github.com/Appollo-CLI/Appollo/issues/34